# Handle file opened from outside application to load WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF app has .xyz files that can open it (used the WIX installer), however, in my WPF app, I'd like to somehow capture this and call some loading functionality of the file that was double-clicked on from the File Explorer before the application was started.

Right now, if you double click the appropriate xyz file from File Explorer, it opens the application but obviously nothing else happens. Is there a way in my WPF code to detect this and call the necessary function passing in the filepath/name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to the file path in your `App.xaml.cs` class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string FilePath { get; private set; }
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        if (e.Args != null && e.Args.Length > 0)
            FilePath = e.Args[0];
    }
}
```

If you store in a static property like this, you could access it from any class in your app:

```
string filePath = App.FilePath;
```

Comment: thanks mm8. Don't understand why i keep getting downvoted :(...

Answer (score 2):

In `Application` there is the `StartUp` event where you can set your arguments.
Follow this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startup?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)